# Using | without putting in an array

Tags: regex

```
(\.|dot)
```

This regex matches all "."s  and "dot"s but it's also puts them into an array. I don't want it. Is there any way to match them without using parentheses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Non-capturing parentheses](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html):

```
(?:\.|dot)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl REs have 'non-capturing groups', other dialects may not.